# SSIS Union and Merge Transformation

Tags: ssis

From two different source, i am merging to a single destination table. Sources have same table schema. I can use UNION ALL. I need the results in a sorted. Which transformation would be ideal, either Merge or Union all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would use a Merge in case you need a to do a join. From your question I feel you need a Union All. Not sure why you need the results sorted, but for that you would need to put in a Sort transform after your Union All.